# java/swing: JSlider.setValue is blocking

Tags: java, swing, jslider

my call to JSlider.setValue is sometimes blocking the thread which results ins a deadlock of the whole application.

here is the stacktrace of the blocking thread.

```
Thread [RenderThread] (Suspended)   
JSlider(Component).getMousePosition() line: not available [local variables unavailable] 
SynthSliderUI.calculateThumbLocation() line: not available [local variables unavailable]    
BasicSliderUI$Handler.stateChanged(ChangeEvent) line: not available 
DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged() line: not available [local variables unavailable]   
DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(int, int, int, int, boolean) line: not available    
DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(int) line: not available  
JSlider.setValue(int) line: not available   
TimeLine.setTime(double) line: 422  
GLFrame.display() line: 302 
GLFrame$2.renderCallback() line: 188    
LWJGLBinding$1.paintGL() line: 49   
LWJGLBinding$1(AWTGLCanvas).paint(Graphics) line: 314   
LWJGLBinding$1(AWTGLCanvas).update(Graphics) line: 343  
GLFrame$2(LWJGLBinding).startRendering() line: 78   
GLFrame$3.run() line: 267
```

this seems to be linked to the nimbus look and feel, cause i doesnt happen in the default look and feel.

```
    try 
    {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

edit:
with invokeLater i do get this exception:

```
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTreeUI.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthTreeUI.update(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.seqPaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SystemEventQueueUtilities$ComponentWorkRequest.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: make sure setValue is called on the EDT

Comment: ok thanks. what is the recommended way to do that?

Comment: `SwingUtilites.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run(){ / *Your code */ }})`

Comment: @Frozen, you should move that to an answer, so @clamp can accept it.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy I thought @kleopatra will do that, so I decided to wait :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing components are not thread-safe. Anything, that modifies Swing component after it is already shown, must be executed in the so-called Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). To achieve this, Swing grants you thee functions:

Two of them serves for code execution:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable)
```

Their purpose comes from their name. Third is

```
SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()
```

If this returns `true`, then you're already in the EDT and may execute code directly.

Note, that `invokeAndWait` will throw an exception, if it is called directly from EDT (`invokeLater` will not, but it is still not recomended to do so), so the code, that may be called from both EDT and side thread, should be written as follows:

```
if (SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
    // code
} else {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable () {
        public void run () {
            // code
        }
    });
}
```

For the purpose of simplicity and readability, you may extract inner code to a method.

Comment: +1 good answer. Just a detail here that when you use [SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) you do not need to make sure it is not run on EDT, which you must do when using [SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29). The exception will be thrown only by invokeAndWait. It is good to check it though as you will not cause your code to go to the end of the queue.

Comment: thanks. actually i do get that exception you are talking about upon startup even though i use invokeLater. see my edit in my originalpost

Comment: @Boro Thanks, corrected that. @clamp Could you please post an exception itself, not just it's stack trace?

Comment: well the exception itself is just a nullpointer exception starting at the stack i posted.

Comment: It seems that you have other Swing-modifying methods, that are invoked not from EDT (see http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4524304). Please check if that is true.